# How do you add 100 colors using a loop into a turtle graphics design code

Tags: python-3.x, colors, turtle-graphics

I am trying to produce color effects that gradually change from dark to light or shift hue for an assignment, but I'm having trouble with figuring out how to put the loop code in for an RGB color that runs 100 different colors.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how loop through many different colors?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import turtle
turtle.setup(width=600, height=500)
turtle.bgcolor("blue")
turtle.reset()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed(0)
for i in range(1000):
    turtle.forward(i)
    turtle.right(98)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

PS. I suppose if I can get some help figuring out how to do the colors, I should probably take out the `BGCOLOR`.

Comment: Any colors in particular? Would you be satisfied with 100 different kinds of gray? :-)

Comment: But I _am_ helping, by requiring you to more stringently state your requirements. Do the colors need to be in a particular order? Disconnected jumble or seamless gradient?

Comment: Ok, sorry Kevin...Let me give you the actual assignment details from the web site about the color portion:                                                                                                                                 turtle.color(r, g, b)
to produce color effects that gradually change from dark to light or shift hue.  That is what the teacher wants, so I am trying to figure out the code that loops that. I know it is 0. something, 0.something, 0.something...at least I think that's right, but I don't know how to state the loop. Again, sorry I thought your were  mocking me:)

Comment: Oops, I wrote an answer before reading the color requirements. Python has a useful [module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/colorsys.html#colorsys.hsv_to_rgb) for getting RGB values for a particular hue. I'll write something about that in a bit.

Comment: @user2744549 I edited your question some to remove the bulk of the non-question content. If I lost anything in the edit or failed to convey that you're looking for guidance and this is not a `give me the codez` question, feel free to edit it again.

Answer (score 4):

First, create a list containing one hundred different colors. Each color should be an RGB tuple, ranging from zero to one. There are many ways to do this, but I just typed in my favorite colors by hand.

```
colors = [
#reddish colors
(1.00, 0.00, 0.00),(1.00, 0.03, 0.00),(1.00, 0.05, 0.00),(1.00, 0.07, 0.00),(1.00, 0.10, 0.00),(1.00, 0.12, 0.00),(1.00, 0.15, 0.00),(1.00, 0.17, 0.00),(1.00, 0.20, 0.00),(1.00, 0.23, 0.00),(1.00, 0.25, 0.00),(1.00, 0.28, 0.00),(1.00, 0.30, 0.00),(1.00, 0.33, 0.00),(1.00, 0.35, 0.00),(1.00, 0.38, 0.00),(1.00, 0.40, 0.00),(1.00, 0.42, 0.00),(1.00, 0.45, 0.00),(1.00, 0.47, 0.00),
#orangey colors
(1.00, 0.50, 0.00),(1.00, 0.53, 0.00),(1.00, 0.55, 0.00),(1.00, 0.57, 0.00),(1.00, 0.60, 0.00),(1.00, 0.62, 0.00),(1.00, 0.65, 0.00),(1.00, 0.68, 0.00),(1.00, 0.70, 0.00),(1.00, 0.72, 0.00),(1.00, 0.75, 0.00),(1.00, 0.78, 0.00),(1.00, 0.80, 0.00),(1.00, 0.82, 0.00),(1.00, 0.85, 0.00),(1.00, 0.88, 0.00),(1.00, 0.90, 0.00),(1.00, 0.93, 0.00),(1.00, 0.95, 0.00),(1.00, 0.97, 0.00),
#yellowy colors
(1.00, 1.00, 0.00),(0.95, 1.00, 0.00),(0.90, 1.00, 0.00),(0.85, 1.00, 0.00),(0.80, 1.00, 0.00),(0.75, 1.00, 0.00),(0.70, 1.00, 0.00),(0.65, 1.00, 0.00),(0.60, 1.00, 0.00),(0.55, 1.00, 0.00),(0.50, 1.00, 0.00),(0.45, 1.00, 0.00),(0.40, 1.00, 0.00),(0.35, 1.00, 0.00),(0.30, 1.00, 0.00),(0.25, 1.00, 0.00),(0.20, 1.00, 0.00),(0.15, 1.00, 0.00),(0.10, 1.00, 0.00),(0.05, 1.00, 0.00),
#greenish colors
(0.00, 1.00, 0.00),(0.00, 0.95, 0.05),(0.00, 0.90, 0.10),(0.00, 0.85, 0.15),(0.00, 0.80, 0.20),(0.00, 0.75, 0.25),(0.00, 0.70, 0.30),(0.00, 0.65, 0.35),(0.00, 0.60, 0.40),(0.00, 0.55, 0.45),(0.00, 0.50, 0.50),(0.00, 0.45, 0.55),(0.00, 0.40, 0.60),(0.00, 0.35, 0.65),(0.00, 0.30, 0.70),(0.00, 0.25, 0.75),(0.00, 0.20, 0.80),(0.00, 0.15, 0.85),(0.00, 0.10, 0.90),(0.00, 0.05, 0.95),
#blueish colors
(0.00, 0.00, 1.00),(0.05, 0.00, 1.00),(0.10, 0.00, 1.00),(0.15, 0.00, 1.00),(0.20, 0.00, 1.00),(0.25, 0.00, 1.00),(0.30, 0.00, 1.00),(0.35, 0.00, 1.00),(0.40, 0.00, 1.00),(0.45, 0.00, 1.00),(0.50, 0.00, 1.00),(0.55, 0.00, 1.00),(0.60, 0.00, 1.00),(0.65, 0.00, 1.00),(0.70, 0.00, 1.00),(0.75, 0.00, 1.00),(0.80, 0.00, 1.00),(0.85, 0.00, 1.00),(0.90, 0.00, 1.00),(0.95, 0.00, 1.00)
]
```

Then, within your loop, choose a color from the list. You need to convert i, which goes from 0 to 999, into an index which goes from 0 to the size of the list. This is most easily done by dividing by ten and converting to an integer. You can then set the color of the turtle using `turtle.color`.

```
for i in range(1000):
    idx = int(i/10)
    color = colors[idx]
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.forward(i)
    turtle.right(98)
```

The result is a magnificent rainbow spiral :-)

[image]

If you do not want to type in three hundred numbers, you can get a lot of vibrant colors by moving around the upper edge of the [HSV cylinder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). Essentially, you keep value and saturation constant, and vary the hue in each iteration of the loop. Python's `colorsys` module will help you convert HSV values into RGB.

Like before, you will need to change i, which varies from 0 to 999, into a hue value, which varies from 0 to 1. This time, divide by 1000, but don't convert to an integer.

```
import colorsys
#turtle setup stuff goes here
for i in range(1000):
    color = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(i/1000, 1.0, 1.0)
    #compatibility quirk: on 2.7 and below, use i/1000.0
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.forward(i)
    turtle.right(98)
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, I tried the latter code and it worked great. Plus I get the idea now of how this loop thing actually works (or at least I am getting there) I don't know why I had trouble figuring out the loop concept with the design, but not with the colors...Anyways I really do appreciate the help.I actually had to drop this class last semester, and I really need to pass it this time around. My specialty is not programming. I am a specialist at Maya and 3DS MAX modeling, texturing, and animation. That stuff I know, this stuff I have trouble with:(...Thanks again Kevin:)

Answer (score 2):

I tried this with a diffrent approach, but it isnt really 100 colors. You could probably change the code a little to get 100. Currently, it would be a rainbow. First i go from red to yellow, to green which goes to cyan that goes to blue, to magenta and back to red.

```
r = 1
g = 0
b = 0
for _ in range(10):
    color(r, g, b)
    #do whatever you have for the moving
    g += 0.1
for _ in range(10):
    color(r, g, b)
    #do the same thing as before
    r -= 1
...
```

The technique used is:
select color to start with,
add color that is clockwise on the rgb color wheel,
subtract color you started with,
add second color,
repeat.
Hope i'm not too late ;)
Edit: Just looked at the date. Oops!
At least some people are probably going to find this anwser useful.